# Unbind jquery in document ready conflict when used in two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages with posts and reviews. The functions for the reply buttons are similar and both using unbind function in document ready event. Somehow, just one function will work even if they are accessing different classes. They both work when one is commented out. I appreciate any help and ideas. Thank you!

```
//Replies Posts
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).unbind().on("click", ".btnReplySubmit", function() {
        if (!$.trim($(this).closest(".myRepliesForm").find(".textareaReply").val())) {
            alert("Empty Content");
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Replies/Create/",
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                data: $(this).closest(".myRepliesForm").serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    $(".reloadComments").load(location.href + " .reloadComments");
                    $(".reloadComments").show("slow");
                }
            });
            $(this).closest(".myRepliesForm").find(".textareaReply").val("");
        }
        return false;
    });
});

//Reply Review
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).unbind().on("click", ".btnReplySubmitReview", function () {
        if (!$.trim($(this).closest(".myRepliesFormReview").find(".textareaReplyReview").val())) {
            alert("Empty Content");
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/ReviewReplies/Create/",
                type: "post",
                cache: false,
                data: $(this).closest(".myRepliesFormReview").serialize(),
                success: function () {
                    $(".reloadCommentsReview").load(location.href + " .reloadCommentsReview");
                    $(".reloadCommentsReview").show("slow");
                }
            });
            $(this).closest(".myRepliesFormReview").find(".textareaReplyReview").val("");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you use `unbind` on both event handlers, one of the functions is going to be inevitably unbound. You also do not need two `ready` calls as one is enough and finally, you can chain your event handler binding as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).unbind()
   .on("click", ".btnReplySubmit", function() {
        if (!$.trim($(this).closest(".myRepliesForm").find(".textareaReply").val())) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
        return false;
    })
    .on("click", ".btnReplySubmitReview", function () {
        if (!$.trim($(this).closest(".myRepliesFormReview").find(".textareaReplyReview").val())) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Because unbind will clear all previous bindings.

But.. why complicating things with bind/unbind on document, you could just do a click listener on both buttons :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.btnReplySubmit').click(function(){
    // alert(1);
  });
  $('.btnReplySubmitReview').click(function(){
    // alert(2);
  })
});
```

Comment: I tried just now this way but the functions only work for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

the main issue I see here is that you are unbinding events attached to `$(document)`. also, according to jquery's api, you shouldn't be using [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) anymore as it is already deprecated.

instead, you should structure your code like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('. btnReplySubmit').click(function() {
    // your code here
  })

  $('. btnReplySubmitReview').click(function() {
    // your code here
  })
})
```

this makes your event declarations much clearer and much easier to read

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are correct. I may just add that the selector in `.on(events [, selector] [,data], handler)` method is the **event trigger**, but event is bound to document in your case.